# IIS with proxy 403 forbidden for axd files

Tags: asp.net, iis, proxy, telerik, url-rewriting

I have following scenario:

ASP.Net website with Telerik Reports. The Telerik ReportViewer uses axd files.
I have a normal http IIS configuration.
With a Router I am connecting over a portal with https to the webserver.
Everything works fine, but if I open a site with the Telerik ReportViewer, the site gives back an error of kind 403 forbidden for an axd file.
I recognized that the added proxy address is missing in the url of the axd file, but I cannot figure out why?

Comment: Nobody had this problem?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the scenario, but have you tried adding a <location> element in the web.config to allow access to this handler for all users?